# No javax in android studio project

Tags: java, android

I tried to run a line of Java code on Android and used the Javax, but during compilation the program produced an error: package javax.tools does not exist import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

I tried to surf the internet, but I got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

`ToolProvider` [is not part of the Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/s/results?q=ToolProvider). I recommend you find some other solution to whatever problem it is that you are trying to solve.

Note that Android devices generally do not have compilers or other development tools installed, let alone ones that are discoverable in the way that `ToolProvider` might support.

Comment: I forget that I tried to import javax.*; and error was like error before

Comment: @Deadli_wolf: It does not matter how you attempt to import it. `ToolProvider` is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: ok sorry, thank you for the help

Comment: @Deadli_wolf Android is *not* a complete implementation of the [Java platform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)).